# Update iOS App Store What’s New while in review?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

Simple question – can we update the “What’s New” text for an update while the app is being reviewed, or after it has been approved but before releasing it?

Comment: You can also change what is new from https://itunesconnect.apple.com While app is approved and online and change reflect after few minutes on App store

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it turns out you can edit it whenever you like, even after the app has gone live, apparently. We apparently had a release with a typo in the update notes a while back and could pop in and fix it after a user tweeted about it.

Comment: It's no longer possible to edit the What's New text after the app has gone live

Answer (score 6):

As of **April 2018**, it's no longer possible to change the *"What's new"* text after the app version changes its status to *In Review*, *Pending Developer Release* or *Ready for Sale*. You have to upload a new build and go through App Review again to change the text.

Nevertheless you can change *"What's new"* text before that, even while it's waiting for review.

Source: [9to5Mac](https://9to5mac.com/2018/03/20/change-whats-new-text-app-review/)

Comment: @Luke this should be the accepted answer as of April 2018 changes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update the What's New text, or the icon, or the screenshots after the app has entered the review process.  That is part of what Apple reviews, so they do not want developers changing the application meta data after they have reviewed it, because there were many app developers that would put screenshots from other, better apps after the review was done.

You can however, update that information while it is in the "Waiting for Review" status.

Comment: Not sure the reason for the down vote.  My answer is backed by Apple documentation at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppMetadata.html